# Cannot retrieve temporary object in child context with existingObjectWithID:error:

Tags: cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord

I have created an object in managed object context, which I haven't saved yet. Further I created a child context and want to modify this object in this context. To be able to modify this object I have to retrieve this temporary object in the child context.

I use MagicalRecord's method `MR_inContext:`, which use the method `existingObjectWithID:error:`. But this doesn't return the object for the given temporary object ID. The method `objectWithID:` does seems to work. I don't understand why `existingObjectWithID:error:` doesn't work but `objectWithID:` does in this case.

```
- (void)testTemporaryObjectInChildContext {
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:SSDProject.class] URLForResource:@"SSDProject" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [coordinator MR_addInMemoryStore];

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_mainQueueContext];
    mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    SSDProject *project = [SSDProject MR_createInContext:mainContext];

    NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_confinementContextWithParent:mainContext];

    // Fails
    NSError *error = nil;
    XCTAssertNotNil([childContext existingObjectWithID:project.objectID error:&error], @"");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    // Succeeds
    XCTAssertNotNil([childContext objectWithID:project.objectID], @"");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `existingObjectWithID:error:` returns `nil` here is simply that the object **doesn't** exist for that context, because it's a temporary object from a different context.

If you create an object in one managed object context but don't save it, it only exists *in that context*. No other managed object context has any way of knowing about it. It's not in memory for them, and since it's not in the persistent store, there's no way for them to find it. When you call `existingObjectWithID:error:`, the context checks what it has in memory and, if necessary, the persistent store. For an unsaved object from a different context, neither check will find anything.

Once you save changes, the object is written to the persistent store file, and then other contexts can find it. At that point, `existingObjectWithID:error:` would return non-`nil` for the ID.

Calling `objectWithID:` will return an object, but not one that you can use. That method assumes that you've provided a valid object ID, so it doesn't check the persistent store. If the object exists, its data will be faulted in normally. If it doesn't, you'll get an exception. This method is useful when you know the object exists and want faster response. In your case the object doesn't exist, so calling this method gives you a time bomb that will blow up your app.

Comment: I always thought that the child contexts fetch objects from their parent contexts before they fetch from the store coordinator even if  the objects are not saved yet. Okay, your explanation that objectWithID: doesn't test if the object exists in the store would explain the difference existingObjectWithID:error:. So the only solution would obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error: ? Does that have any downsides?

Comment: The downside is that it's not a solution. You'll get a permanent ID, sure, but the object still doesn't exist in the persistent store, so other contexts still can't find it. You do need a permanent ID, but it's not enough on its own. The other context must have some way of locating the object.

Comment: The object shouldn't be visible to other contexts, only to the child context. And the only way to make it locatable in the child context without saving the parent context is by using obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error: unfortunately.

Comment: A child context *is* another context.

Comment: I have one one child context (main queue) saving into a parent (private queue), and then another child, which shares the same parent, retrieving the object using it's objectID.  I was under the assumption that this would work, since everything you read says that a parent context is treated like it's children's permanent store, but found that, no, I have to save the parent to the (real) permanent store in order for this to work.  Doesn't seem to matter if the objectIDs are temporary or permanent.

Comment: I had the same idea as Stephan, so colour me surprised as well.
I also noticed the following for a parent context with two sibling child contexts where one child context has been saved. The parent context has no persistent store (unsaved document). So all objectID's are temporary. Retrieving objects with existingObjectWithID does not work. Do a fetch (via executeFetchRequest) beforehand and existingObjectWithID will work. Surprisingly objectWithID work as well (even without any fetch).

Comment: The thing about `objectWithID:` is, it **always** returns an object, as its documentation says. Whether it "works" is a different matter-- it assumes that you know what you're doing and returns an object with no data, but which can be used to retrieve data via Core Data faults. But if you used a bogus object ID, you get a bogus object back, and firing those faults will fail.

Answer (score 0):

`objectWithID:` always returns an object, but it may not be valid (and could throw an exception when you try to use it). `existingObjectWithID:error:` checks for existence before it returns and returns nil if the object couldn't be found. So, using `existingObjectWithID:error:` is the safe option.

You should save the new object before trying to access it in another context, or just don't use another context (it isn't clear why you want to do what you're trying to do...).

Comment: I use multiple contexts for staged changes, so that I can discard each child context with its changes. Unfortunately I cannot save the previous context. Also I don't want to use objectWithID:, because I cannot be completely sure that that the object always exists.

Comment: So why are you creating the object in the parent context if you aren't going to save it?

Comment: Simplified, the user can cancel the process and discard all changes.

Comment: I still don't see why that precludes creating it in the child context. That's what you need to do...