# Deleting object from fresh child context

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a strange behaviour while deleting object from a fresh child context.

I have a Managed Object Context using the main queue.
I fetch a list of objects from it.
I create the new context, using a private queue.
I set its parent to be the main context.

Of course, I can't try to directly delete the objects from the list in the child context. So I used existingObjectWithID: to make a list of "equivalent" object from the child context.
Core Data tells me he can't find those objects :

> Error domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain code: 133000
>
> Attempt to access an object not found in store.
>
> No additional error info

And of course, I can't delete them.

Now, if I fetch the list of objects in the child context, they are found and I can delete them (but that would be cheating, I am not supposed to know how to fetch this list).

What's the trick ??? Isn't existingObjectWithID: supposed to fetch from the parent context if objects are not (yet) in the child context ?

Comment: mainQueueContext attached **directly** to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`(bad idea).  **There is no trick.** See a similar question here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511745/cannot-retrieve-temporary-object-in-child-context-with-existingobjectwithiderro).

Comment: Thanks. The link indeed describes completely the problem I have. Well, I guess I have to re-think my stack architecture and the life cycle of my contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom Harrington's answer in this post ([Cannot retrieve temporary object in child context with existingObjectWithID:error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511745/cannot-retrieve-temporary-object-in-child-context-with-existingobjectwithiderro)) fully explains the problem.

The only solution for me is to re-think the context stack and context life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these objects are saved already and not temporary objects, which behave a bit differently.

If you know the objects exist already, you can use `objectWithID` instead of `existingObjectWithID`.  Note that you'll always get an object back this way, but it may not be valid, so you have to check.

Although all the documentation says that a parent context behaves like the permanent backing store of child contexts, in practice it doesn't work this way -- which is why fetching the objects directly from the child context works for you.

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem is closer to the above comment of Khundragpan. In fact, as the main context saving is done asynchronously, I can't be sure when the objects are saved or not. I will re-think my stack and the life cycle of y contexts.